# android:Screen Capture

Tags: android-emulator

I know how to capture the screen shot through ddms option in Android.
but i want to create a application havinga button, which when cliked will capture its ui and store it in sdcard.
please me with your valueable ideas.
Regards,
puneet

Answer (score 1):

@Jokahero: MonkeyDevice seems to be useable only from adb. You simply can't take a screenshot on Android if your device is not rooted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [MonkeyDevice.takeSnapshot()](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/MonkeyDevice.html#takeSnapshot)